# How to share same constructors across different classes aka define constructors in an interface?

Tags: android, kotlin

Let's say I have multiple custom views in Android with same constructors

```
class Button: AppCompatButton {

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
    }

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
    }
    //Some custom implementation
    //............
}

class TextView: AppCompatTextView {

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
    }

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
    }
    //Some custom implementation
    //............
}
```

So I need some interface or base class which allow me to inherit form multiple views like TextView, Button, EditText, etc.

Something like

```
abstract class BaseView<T : View> : T {
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
    }

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
    }
}
```

Or

```
interface ViewConstructor {
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
    }

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
    }
}
```

So I just use one interface or base class and do not copy past contractors again and again.How to achieve such goal in Kotlin?

P.S. Please do not suggest use base class as View and create derived views using base class. I'm using XML and I need EditText, Button and other views as it is.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: I just stumbled upon this answer, and it needs updating. Using `@JvmOverloads` could be an issue in certain custom views, as calling any of the constructors generated for your own class will first delegate into the all-params constructor within the class, and then call the all-params constructor of the super, instead of each constructor calling into the super method with the matching amount of parameters. See [this article](https://blog.q42.nl/the-danger-of-assumptions-kotlin-with-android-custom-views-adb79bf2da45) (for example) for details on that.

Original text of my answer below.

---

As a solution to having to write that many constructors, you can use default arguments combined with `@JvmOverloads` to get all 4 `View` constructors easily, while only writing a primary constructor for your class:

```
class CustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyleAttr: Int = 0,
        defStyleRes: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely unlikely you will find a solution to your problem. For one, constructors are not inherited in the way you suggest. They exist to initialize your part of the inheritance chain so anyone that inherits from you would still need to forward to the super classes constructor. I'm fairly certain you're stuck redeclaring those view constructors in each View class (although some of them you could probably drop based on your instantiation use case).